# Dynamic row heights with react-virtualized and new CellMeasurer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using react-virualized 9 with Autosizer, List, and CellMeasurer components.  I need to update the row heights when the list data has changed.  It appears that since the changes to support React Fiber in version 9 the only public method for CellMeasurer is now measure(). Most of the examples use the previous resetMeasurementForRow() method.  The current [CellMeasurer doc](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md) doesn't seem to have any info on the new public methods. Not sure if I've overlooked something but any help is appreciated.

```
const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  defaultHeight: 60,
  fixedWidth: true
});

<AutoSizer>
  {({ width, height }) => (
    <List
      deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
      height={height}
      ref={element => { this.list = element; }}
      rowCount={list.length}
      rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
      rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
      width={width}
    />
  )}
</AutoSizer>

rowRenderer({ index, key, parent, style }) {
  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={cache}
      columnIndex={0}
      key={key}
      overscanRowCount={10}
      parent={parent}
      ref={element => { this.cellMeasurer = element; }}
      rowIndex={index}
    >
      {({ measure }) => {
        this.measure = measure.bind(this);

        return <MyList index={index} data={list[index]} style={style} />;
      }}
    </CellMeasurer>
  );
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // Some change in data occurred, I'll probably use Immutable.js here
  if (this.props.list.length !== nextProps.list.length) {
    this.measure();
    this.list.recomputeRowHeights();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide `this.measure()` function content? I am trying to implement dynamic row height but my list item rows are completely different.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I need to update the row heights when the list data has changed.
>   The current CellMeasurer doc doesn't seem to have any info on the new public methods.

Admittedly the docs could be improved, with regard to the new `CellMeasurer`. In this case though, you need to do 2 things in respond to your row data/sizes changing:

1. If a specific list-item has changed size then you need to clear its cached size so it can be remeasured. You do this by calling `clear(index)` on `CellMeasurerCache`. (Pass the `index` of the row that's changed.)
2. Next you'll need to let `List` know that its size information needs to be recalculated. You do this by calling [`recomputeRowHeights(index)`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#recomputerowheights-index-number). (Pass the `index` of the row that's changed.)

For an example of something similar to what you're describing, check out the example [Twitter-like app](https://tweets.now.sh/) I built with react-virtualized. You can see the source [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/tweets/blob/37d0139736346db16b9681d5b859a4e127964518/src/components/TweetList.js#L126-L132).

Comment: do you have any demo code for how to use clear(index) ?

Comment: @bvaughn you saved me! I was so stuck on this until I saw here i gotta clear the cache before recomputing. Thank you SO MUCH

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.props.list.length !== nextProps.list.length) {
  cache.clearAll();
}
```

This helped me! :)

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.