# row height is not changing after data is changed using sorting method in react-virtualized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am rendering a long list using the react-virtualized library. everything is working fine, but when I sort the data using the javascript sort method then the height of the divs doesn't change when the data changes. how can I change the height also when the data changes? I have been searching for a solution for 3 days but all the solutions are in the functional component.

here is my code

```
export default function App() {
  const cache = React.useRef(
    new CellMeasurerCache({
      fixedWidth: true,
      defaultHeight: 100,
    })
  );
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPeople(
      [...Array(1000).keys()].map((key) => {
        return {
          id: key,
          name: `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`,
          bio: faker.lorem.lines(Math.random() * 100),
        };
      })
    );
  }, []);



  const ascending = (index) => {
    const filter = [...people].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    setPeople(filter)
  }
  const decending = () => {
    const filter = [...people].sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name))
    setPeople(filter)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={ascending}>ascending</button>
      <button onClick={decending}>decending</button>

      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => (
            <List
              width={width}
              height={height}
              rowHeight={cache.current.rowHeight}
              deferredMeasurementCache={cache.current}
              rowCount={people.length}
              rowRenderer={({ key, index, style, parent }) => {
                const person = people[index];

                return (
                  <CellMeasurer
                    key={key}
                    cache={cache.current}
                    parent={parent}
                    columnIndex={0}
                    rowIndex={index}
                  >
                    <div style={style}>
                      <h2>{person.name}</h2>
                      <p>{person.bio}</p>
                    </div>
                  </CellMeasurer>
                );
              }}
            />
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share an executable demo? Initial guess is, weird side-effect of using index as `key`.

Comment: sure. he is my codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-demo-sxk9f2 .

Answer (score 1):

After changing the order, you need to clear the cache:

```
  const ascending = (index) => {
    const filter = [...people].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    setPeople(filter);
    cache.current.clearAll();
  };
```

See: [Dynamic row heights with react-virtualized and new CellMeasurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837279/dynamic-row-heights-with-react-virtualized-and-new-cellmeasurer)

Working snippet - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-demo-forked-wwgu16

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope this discussion will also help others in the future.