# Table with dynamic row heights and loading

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm using react-virualized 9 with Table, Autosizer, and CellMeasurer components. I need to update the row heights when the list data has changed. Based on [the answer from the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43837929/21617288), I need to do 2 steps:

- `clear(index)` on `CellMesurerCache`
- calling `recomputeRowHeights(index)` on `Table`.

The problem is that it's hard for me to determine which row has changed. The reason is that I'm using `redux`. When new data comes in, I need to compare it with previous data, which is huge and expensive.

I've tried to use `clearAll()`, but doing this causes the table scroll view to jump. Because the rowHeights were reset to minHeight, then expanded again to the actual heights.

I'm wondering is there any better solutions way to achieve dynamic row heights without knowing the exact changing index. Thank you in advance!